# Are non-Muslims discouraged from wearing traditional Muslim clothes?

Tags: practical-islam, hijab, culture, respect

I am not a follower of Islam or any other sect of Christianity or Judaism. Despite the differences in many of the ideals and teachings from these religions and what I believe, I feel that I should wear a hijab and/or jilbab and otherwise dress modestly with some sort or head covering or scarf. I believe that each person should do what they feel is best for them, and by that logic, I know that I should cover and be modest, but I am also concerned with how others would feel about me doing so. I would be wearing the coverings so that others see me for my inner self and not judge me on my outward appearance, because I believe it is the right thing to do, and because I would like to keep my whole self to myself, those close to me, and the Divine/Spirit. However, I do not want to offend anyone with my ignorance, either culturally or religiously.

Is there anything in Islam that restricts or discourages non-Muslims from wearing such traditionally Muslim garments?

Comment: Quranic verses are [guide for those who do good](http://quranx.com/31.3) . there is no prohibition on honestly emulating Islamic way of life. But [those who mock are despised](http://quranx.com/5.57?allTranslations=y).

Comment: No, you can wear whatever you like! it's not against Islam to cover yourself when you are not Muslim :)

Answer (score 2):

Asalam u Alaykum (Peace be upon you)

Following the teachings of islam includes everything i.e, dress code, food grade ...
and anyone can adhere to it. Because it is for whole mankind and every generation to come.
It is for the betterment of mankind. So following even the Dress code is highly appreciated
Your intention is the same as is required for hijab thats really good.

If you think what others might think about you, I say leave them to their worries, protect your interests, I too don't think what others might or do or will think about me, (my way my will.).

And every muslim should respect your choice, because Islam is for everyone. :)

P.S. -  I am a muslim

---